# How do I transform an image to a different size based on a set of control and target coordinates?

Tags: javascript, matrix, coordinate-transformation

I have a set of control coordinates and a set of target coordinates and I need to figure out how to transform an image over that given set of coordinates. For eg: I want (0,0) of the new image to be (10,20) of the old image or (100, 75) of the new Image to be (40, 30) of the old Image. I dont know if it matters, but I am doing this through javascript.

Comment: Right now I am using something along the lines in this answer: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32555/how-do-i-convert-between-two-different-2d-coordinate-systems But I have a feeling I may be doing it wrong

Comment: Unfortunately I couldnt find an existing library to do what I wanted so I started working on one myself. I will post it as soon as I know it is working and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, here is the library I coded to make this happen. It took a lot of research and looking around, but in the end it all paid off. The concept is called Affine Fit Transformation. More info can be found here: https://github.com/clockwork189/Affinity